# Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox disk full error: "ahci-0-3" (rc=VERR_DISK_FULL)

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, windows-10, disk-usage

On my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, I installed VirtualBox and added Windows 10 to it. Currently, Windows won't launch because VirtualBox experiences an error stating the following infoprmation:

"An error has occurred during virtual machine execution! The error details are shown below. You may try..."

DETAILS:
"The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-3"
(rc=VERR_DISK_FULL). Make sure there is enough free space on...."

"ERROR ID: BLKCACHE_IOERR"
"SEVERITY: Non-fatal Error"

Comment: Have you tried making more room on the disk?

Comment: The **recommended minimum** disk space is 25GB, but that's only a minimum and varies on what you want to do with it.  The more software and data you add, the more space you'll require.

Comment: I don't think it is full, but could be wrong. In VB settings under "Storage -> Storage Devices -> Windows 10 Virtual.vdi," the following information displays on the right:

Virtual size of 121.55 GB
Actual size of 53.58 GB
Details: Dynamically allocated
Location: /media/salmm/Files/VirtualBox_In_Linux/Windows 10 Virtual.vdi
Attached to: Windows 10 Vurtual

Comment: The error message that you cut short explains the problem: Your *Host* has no more storage space. If you would like confirmation, [edit] your question to show the full output of `df -h` 

Comment: I found out that the partition the vdi was on had no space left. Thank you all. Can I copy the vdi to another partition and use it on Ubuntu 20.04? I have an SSD on that OS.